# Counting records in normalized table

Tags: mysql, count, normalize

### Older questions seen

- [Counting one table of records for matching records of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5745686/1190388)
- [MySQL Count matching records from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13271843/1190388)
- [Count records from two tables grouped by one field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12429347/1190388)

### Table(s) Schema

Table **`entries`** having data from `2005-01-25`

```
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ctg` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `msg` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `nick` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `msg` (`msg`),
    INDEX `date` (`date`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Child table **`magnets`** with *regular* data from `2011-11-08`(There might be a few entries from before that)

```
CREATE TABLE `magnets` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `eid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tth` CHAR(39) NOT NULL,
    `size` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `nick` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'hjpotter92',
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `eid_tth` (`eid`, `tth`),
    INDEX `entriedID` (`eid`),
    INDEX `tth_size` (`tth`, `size`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

### Question

I want to get the count of total number of entries by any particular `nick`(or user) entered in either of the table.

One of the entry in `entries` is populated at the same time as `magnets` and the subsequent entries of `magnets` can be from the same `nick` or different.

### My Code

- Try 1

  ```
  SELECT `e`.id, COUNT(1), `e`.nick, `m`.nick
  FROM `entries` `e`
  INNER JOIN `magnets` `m`
      ON `m`.`eid` = `e`.id
  GROUP BY `e`.nick
  ```
- Try 2

  ```
  SELECT `e`.id, COUNT(1), `e`.nick
  FROM `entries` `e`
  GROUP BY `e`.nick
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `m`.eid, COUNT(1), `m`.nick
  FROM `magnets` `m`
  GROUP BY `m`.nick
  ```

The second try is generating some relevant outputs, but it contains double entries for all the `nick` which appear in both tables.

Also, I don't want to count twice, those entries/magnets which were inserted in the first query. Which is what the second `UNION` statement is doing. It takes in all the values from both tables.

### SQL Fiddle link

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3540/1) is the link to a SQL Fiddle along with randomly populated entries.

I really hope someone can guide me through this. If it's any help, I will be using PHP for final display of data. So, my last resort would be to nest loops in PHP for the counting(which I am currently doing).

### Desired output

The output that should be generated on the fiddle should be:

```
************************************************
**        Nick        |||        Count        **
************************************************
**        Nick1       |||         10          **
**        Nick2       |||          9          **
**        Nick3       |||          6          **
**        Nick4       |||         10          **
************************************************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more efficient way but this works if I understand correctly:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt), nick FROM
(SELECT count(*) cnt, e.nick FROM entries e 
  LEFT JOIN magnets m ON (e.id=m.eid AND e.nick=m.nick) 
  WHERE eid IS NULL GROUP BY e.nick
UNION ALL
  SELECT count(*) cnt, nick FROM magnets m GROUP BY nick) u 
GROUP BY nick
```

Comment: Made one update.  It needs to be `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`, to be more generally correct.